# Organise a GUI RMI client in swing

Tags: java, swing

I am developing a secured phone-book in RMI with a GUI in swing.

My question is more related to the Class structure for the Client GUI than RMI itself.

So basically, my GUI opens a at first a JFrame with a login/password when you click on the Connect button, if authentication is okay, another JFrame is opened and show the content of the phone-book.
But I don't know if I need to put everything in the same java file as Inner class or create a new class with the new JFrame. It's probably a matter of choice but I want it in the proper way.
In top of that I don't know where it's better to get the phone book RMI reference

```
public class ClientGui extends JFrame {
private static final String registryhost= "localhost:1099"; 
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
//Several attributes

public ClientGui() {
    //Creation of components and a Connect Button
}

private class ButtonConnect implements ActionListener { 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        try {
            Phonebook phonebook = (Phonebook) Naming.lookup("rmi://"+registryhost+"/Phonebook");
            Customer customerInstance = phonebook.checkCredential(login, password);

            if(customerInstance!=null) {
                CustomerPage page=new CustomerPage();
                page.setVisible(true);
                JLabel label = new JLabel("Welcome");
                page.getContentPane().add(label);
            } 
        } catch (RemoteException e3) {
            //blabla
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    try
    {
        ClientGui frame=new ClientGui();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());}
}
```

}

As you see the phone book reference is received when clicking on the connect button. But I don't think it's good idea because the new Jframe also have to use this RMI reference. 
So what is the best way ? Storing the RMI attribute as static in the Client GUI attributes and the new JFrame as an Inner Class ? Or creating another class for the new JFrame but it needs a new

```
Phonebook phonebook = (Phonebook) Naming.lookup("rmi://"+registryhost+"/Phonebook");
```